# Android Studio - Layout

Tags: android-studio, directory

Hello im a beginner in Android Studio,

I'm working on a project with a classmate and we now have about 20 Layouts in
our current Porject. Is there **any way** to

**create Folders inside the /res/layout Directory** to make it easier to handle.

When I try to make folders they dont show up in the Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the layout folder then go to new and then click on directory.